# Администрирование сайта

Tags: wordpress

Я откликнулся на фрилансе на один заказ, мне нужно опубликовывать статьи на сайте, мне дали пароль от сайта и все. Мне нужно стать одним из админов но логина не дали и давать не хотят, мне как то с помощью wordpress домена и пароля нужно узнать логин или как то его зарегистрировать(свой)

Comment: Никак вы не узнаете. Запрашивайте у клиента.

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, что заказчик не даёт связку из логина и пароля. Если честно, зависит от задачи (может Вам права администратора и не нужны). В таком случае можно попросить, чтобы заказчик создал учётную запись с нужными правами. И предоставил доступ.